# Holding down a key issue (self.AutoHotkey)

Tags: autohotkey

The issue seems to be that if you hold down a key it seems to be spamming the command instead of sending it once. For example I would like the command

```
k::Send ^ n
```

to send a single <kbd>ctrl + n</kbd> if I hold the <kbd>k</kbd> key down, but it seems to spam it infinitely. How do I make it happen only once?

Answer (score 1):

```
$k::
Send ^n
KeyWait, k  ; wait for k to be released
return
```

or

```
$k up:: Send ^n  ; if you want to send a command by releasing a key
```

Press k longer than 0,5 seconds to send ^n:

```
$k::
KeyWait, k, T0.5
If (!ErrorLevel)
  Send k
else
{
  Send ^n
  KeyWait, k
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with

```
k::
    if(getKeyState("k","P"))
        return
    send ^n
return
```

This would check if <kbd>k</kbd> is pressed down already physically, and if so, not do anything.

Comment: Your script makes sense to me, but for some reason when I try it the command doesn't get executed at all, not even once.

Comment: I'm guessing that it returns from the very first check and never executes the send command

Comment: Yes, that's why my answer is completely useless